# Logic App calling WebAPI with managed identity what kind of token is added to request

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity

In Azure I have a working logic app with a managed identity calling a WebAPI endpoint using a HTTP step. The endpoint is now decorated to AllowAnonymous. But I would like the get to the token/claims. If in case they are added by the logic app. So the thing I would like to know is a token (bearer,jwt) added by the Logic App? And some example code to get to them would be nice.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]   
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("API/datatest/handle/{Id}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HandleAsync(Data data, string Id)
    {
    //get to the token/claims here.
    }

    //or by attribute.
    [GetLoginAppTokenData]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("API/datatest/handle/{Id}")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HandleAsync(Data data, string Id)
    {
    //do moreenter code here
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or google to find out how to get token from an API header?

Comment: How to do handle the login challenge process to generate these token?

Comment: That is taken care of Azure Active directory. When you set up the Managed Identity object, Azure will create an object Id. Then when you want to use the managed identiy you select it in your logic app, but you also need to point to a Audience (which live inside your Azure Active Directry) and this will probably create the token, and hopefully as a authorization header in the logic app HTTP request. I will try debug the logic app locally when it triggers but not sure it will work. If so then I could look inside the request (Httpcontext) myself.

Comment: It will attach a JWT to the request. Make sure the logic app gets a token for your API (so using a resource that matches your API). Then setup AAD JWT authentication in your API, there are various samples that show you how to do this.

Comment: Any update now?

Comment: The setup is all good now. Debugging at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

1.Go to logic app> `Identity`> Turn `on` System assigned.

[image]

2.Go to the webapp >`Authentication / Authorization`> Turn on Azure Active Directory Authentication Provider. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad).

3.Go to the webapp>`Access Control(IAM)`>Add>`Add role assignment`, add role like `Contributor` to your service principal of your logic app.

[image]

4.Go to logic app `designer` add `Http` connector to authenticate access with managed identity.

Set `Authentication` as `Managed Identity` and add `Audience` as your webapp app `clientId` which registered in azure ad.

[image]

Then you could use Logic App MSI to visit Webapp. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity).

Comment: Thank you Joey will start working with your answer now and will accept after.